# Blender High/Low vertices versions in same object

Tags: modeling, rendering, objects

I would like to make two versions of the same mesh, one version for test rendering with few vertices, and the other version for final rendering with all vertices.

I haven't been using Blender for some years, and stuck on trying figure out how I do this. Vaguely remember it should be possible.

Would be happy if someone either can explain how this can be done or post some relevant links. Well, or tell me this is not possible, so I can stop wasting time searching the subject:)

Sorry for not very useful tags, but really have no idea what this feature is called. And thanks in advance.

Comment: Most modifiers and relevant properties have two "quality" settings, one for rendering and one for viewport.

Comment: You probably refer to the "Multiresolution" modifier?